# Do web applications create a new table for each users data?

Tags: database, web-applications

Sorry in advance if this is a silly question, but I am very new to web-application design.

In `web-apps` where users are able to create and manage their own data, how does the `database/back-end` implementation work?

E.g. in a web-application: a user is able to create a list of tasks and time to complete them by.

Should the back end be creating a *new table* for *each user'*s tasks?

I ask as surely the data for different users should be completely seperated to each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a table, containing all tasks
when a user creates a new task/list of tasks or whatever you call them
the new entry is added to the table

Comment: Yes but would say: USER1 and USER2's tasks all be added to the one table? :S

Comment: yes
u can separate different users' entries, say, by 'userID' key for example :3

Comment: ok, Just wasnt sure, thanks, so a web-app will never really create new tables on a user click etc?

Comment: Correct. Only - maybe - on first-time-init or upgrade.